# DMA SPI performance

Tags: microcontroller, spi, arm, computer-architecture, dma

I am currently writing an SD card driver for a Microcontroller using SPI and DMA. The SPI has a FIFO that can store 4 data values from the data register which has the capable of storing 32 bit. But it is also possible to write 8 bit to the data register.

When using Regular SPI without DMA. I can tell that there is no performance difference between sending 32 bits in one go and sending 8 bits in 4 times.

So my question whether there is a performance difference between using DMA to fill the FIFO and filling the FIFO with 32 bit? If there is, is it a big difference in performance (The SPI transfer speed and effects on the CPU)

Edit: My MCU is a nxp S32K148. It also noted that there are parallel tasks for the CPU to work on since this SPI is for data logging.

Comment: Which MCU model it is?

Comment: It is a NXP S32K148

Comment: What speed are you running your SPI clock? Are there other tasks you micro is (or will be) doing at the same time?

Comment: I will be running the SPI clock at around 14MHz (max frequency) and yes. As this SPI acts as a data logger, there will be lots of intense tasks going on in the mean time for the CPU to handle.